Fitter compatible with Python 3.9 version
I completed a pip install fitter in my new python environment. I can confirm by checking using "pip list" in my environment, however when I am importing the fitter library in my Jupyter environment, then I get a "Module not found" error.
Could someone please help?

Did you run the magic command %pip list from inside the notebook where you are trying to import? Jupyter doesn't necessarily connect with environment you run it in. Often extra steps are involved but since you don't say how you set up this new environment, we cannot advise really well. The easiest solution, even if you had described things well, may be be to run the magic %pip install fitter in the running notebook where you are planning to next run the import statement. Restart the kernel after running the magic install command. You may need to actually restart everything depending ...

 on how complex the installation would normally be & how much stuff it needs to change throughout your system. Plus, you should even force a reload in your Jupyter page so you know the page did a full refresh if there were settings i javascript and things. Usually with something like Pandas these extra steps are unnecessary while it is very necessary with ipywidgets and ipympl. I'm not familiar with fitter so I cannot say. See my answer here for more information and how with magic you can run pip list in the right environment.

HEy Marc, thanks for your answer. I am running  pip list in conda command prompt and i am seeing fitter library in my vistual environment , which i created using this command :  python -m venv . I have the fitter library in muy base environment . So when i am running an import  using Jupyter notebook in my Venv i am still not able to find the library. However, the magic install helped but frankly, how to do if i want to run a requirements file ?

pip list in the conda prompt just runs it in the environment you made. You need to connect Jupyter to the environment. The two top scoring answers here cover this. Alternatively, %pip install -r requirements.txt works from inside a running notebook. Ideally though you'd use %conda install with an environment.yml file though because you should endeavor to install everything you can with Anaconda/conda since you have pointed out you are at the conda prompt and so Anaconda/conda is your primary package manager ...

 by choice. Don't mix and match if you want your environments robust & portable.
